# How to change AlertDialog font style in Android?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, typeface

I want to change the AlertDialog font style in android , by setting a type face.

Answer (score 0):

Put your typeface.ttf file in asset folder and then use the below code

```
TextView txtview = new TextView(this);
     txtview.setText("hello world");
     txtview.setTypeface(<typeface.ttf>);

 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alert.setTitle("Your title");
     alert.setView(txtview);
     alert.setNeutralButton("Close", null);
     alert.setCancelable(true);
     alert.show();
```

Comment: Do you want to change font style of some textview of alertdialogbox or something else you want?

Comment: the font style of the alertdialog title and buttons .

Comment: Thank you but i can't add buttons there.

Comment: You can. Instead of using `alert.setView(txtview);` try creating your own layout for the dialog and using `alert.setView(yourLayout);`.
That will allow you to put any content you want inside of the dialog including changing the typeface for any buttons/text/labels by implementing the method shown above.

Comment: yes ,Thanks but how to control its dimenssions as the alertdialog set its dimenssion by default for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

you can't set the typeface directly with the builder.
But you can do it with the [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) instance after you've created it.

So:

1. Set all the flags you need with the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) instance.
2. create the [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) instance with the [create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29) method.
3. instance the custom typeface with [Typeface.createFromAssets(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset%28android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String%29)
4. look for the views you want to style with [yourCreatedAlertDialog.findViewById( id )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#findViewById%28int%29) and apply the typeface.

Comment: is there any example plz.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own style in style.xml

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!--item RadioButton or CheckBox color-->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#ffffff</item>
    <!--item text color-->
    <item name="textColorAlertDialogListItem">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--buttons color-->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ffffff</item>
    <!--title and message color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--dialog background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/back_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/yourfont</item>
</style>
```

and then use it in your `AlertDialog.Builder`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
```